# Rewrite Performance, and rules that work in .htaccess but not vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost, .htaccess

I'm working on moving my .htaccess rules over to our vhost_ssl.conf file. I'm hitting some snags with rules that worked fine in .htaccess but aren't working in vhost. For example, in .htaccess this works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^example$ /example/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^example/$ somewhere/something.php [QSA,L]
```

With the idea being that if someone visits example.com/example - they get redirected to example.com/example/ (just adding the trailing slash). Then the trailing slash version of the URL gets rewritten behind the scenes.

When I move this over to vhost:

```
RewriteRule ^/example/$ somewhere/something.php [QSA,L]
```

I hit a couple of snags:

1. it turns into an infinite loop of redirects (my server stops it at 10), because the first rule is always triggered
2. after I comment out the first rule, I get a "Bad Request" 400 error:

> Bad Request
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.
>   Client sent malformed Host header

Any ideas why this might be happening? We're running apache/nginx if that means anything. I read another thread on SF for a similar issue, and the response was that it's a context issue and to add a leading slash to the final destination on the rewrite. But in my case when I do that:

```
RewriteRule ^/example/$ /somewhere/something.php [QSA,L]
```

The error changes to:

```
Unable to execute 'example/': No such file or directory
```

Also on the performance side of this in vhost, is there any difference between, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^/example/$ somewhere/something.php [QSA,L]
```

vs

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/$
RewriteRule .* somewhere/something.php [QSA,L]
```

Seems to me that the first version would be superior, it should accomplish the same goal but in less lines. But maybe having the RewriteCond separately makes it more efficient overall?

EDIT: Here's the vhost_ssl

```
RewriteEngine on
#canonocanconcical fix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !Per_Page=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} show=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule c-([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\.htm c-$1.htm?Per_Page=%1 [QSA,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !CatListingOffset=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Offset=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule c-([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\.htm /c-$1.htm?CatListingOffset=%1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Check your setting of `RewriteBase`.

Comment: there is no RewriteBase. Is one required?

Comment: No, RewriteBase directive is available only in htaccess, not in the main config.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remember to add the leading slash
2. Read the Apache documentation, especially the part about where you often don't need mod_rewrite for a lot of things (which can be handled with mod_alias): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html
3. Remember that - even with flag L the rewriting may not be done, but starts over again at the top. This will often explain the infinite loops, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481199/2444812
4. If you can't figure it out, create a minimal example (preferably on local or dev system, not on production) and enable mod_rewrite logging, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite

---

### 1. Remember to add the leading slash

Works in .htaccess (but not in general configuration):

```
RewriteRule ^example$ /example/ [L,R=301]
```

Works in general configuration:

```
RewriteRule ^/example$ /example/ [L,R=301]
```

The difference is the leading slash (/).

I recommend to ***always*** use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?example$ /example/ [L,R=301]
```

... **which will work in both** (because it makes the leading slash optional). Then you will not have this problem now or in the future when you move the rules from .htaccess to general configuration (or vice versa).

See the documentation:

> In per-directory context (i.e., within .htaccess files and Directory blocks), these rules are being applied after a URL has already been translated to a filename. Because of this, the URL-path that mod_rewrite initially compares RewriteRule directives against is the full filesystem path to the translated filename *with the current directories path (including a trailing slash) removed from the front*.

and

> In particular, remember that `the leading directory path will be stripped off of the URL`

(... in .htaccess context)

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/tech.html

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating, you can match the same url with and without a trailing slash using the `?` quantifier and a single rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^example/?$ http://example.com/somewhere/something.php [L,R=301]
```

To avoid loops, make sure that `example` != `somewhere`.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this isn't working. I don't know why, but nothing redirects/rewrites when I add that to my vhost, reconfigure, and refresh the page. Instead the browser stays at the entered URL (example.com/example) and shows the 404 page. Also, if this did work, wouldn't it do a 301 redirect to the destination page, instead of a rewrite? So the browser URL would change to /somewhere/something.php. I only want it to change to add the trailing slash. Once the trailing slash is there, I want it to be a behind the scenes rewrite.

Comment: Can you post the whole vhost_ssl.conf file

Comment: all set, it's part of the main question now

Comment: I found the problem - it's not the rewrites at all, it's a problem with our ecommerce platform. The rewrites are working as intended, I just thought the errors I was getting were because the rewrites were wrong. They're not - the destination page (our ecommerce platform) doesn't understand them. If I send them to a normal .htm or .php page, they work fine. So unfortunately, there's no answer to this question :/